# Memory Leak in C++ at template

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

In visual studio `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` has detected memory leaks! But I could not find how it is happening. Please tell me what is wrong with the following code.?

```
// Declaration
template <class T> class cMatrix {
 private:
  std::vector<std::vector<T> > mat;
  unsigned rows;
  unsigned cols;

 public:
  cMatrix(unsigned _rows, unsigned _cols, const T& _initial);
  cMatrix(const cMatrix<T>& rhs);
  virtual ~cMatrix();
}


//Constructor 
template<class T>
cMatrix<T>::cMatrix(unsigned _rows, unsigned _cols, const T& _initial) {
  mat.resize(_rows);
  for (unsigned i=0; i<mat.size(); i++) {
    mat[i].resize(_cols, _initial);
  }
  rows = _rows;
  cols = _cols;
}

//VirtualDestructor
template<class T>
cMatrix<T>::~cMatrix() {}
```

Comment: Show the code that uses this template.

Comment: There are no discernible leaks in the code you posted.  How is it being used?

Comment: int main() {cMatrix<double> mat1(2, 3, 23.0), mat4(2, 3, 15.0); _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); }

Comment: @user3207079 put that to your post - make all (the post) compile and show the leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); is called in the same scope as vector is, so object does not get destroyed when it is called.

This won't show any memory leaks:

```
int main() 
{
{
cMatrix<double> mat1(2, 3, 23.0), mat4(2, 3, 15.0); 
}
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); 
}
```

By the way, more efficient way to define cMatrix would be

```
// Declaration
template <class T> class cMatrix {
 private:
  std::vector<std::vector<T> > mat;
  unsigned rows;
  unsigned cols;

 public:
  cMatrix(unsigned _rows, unsigned _cols, const T& _initial);
  virtual ~cMatrix();
};


//Constructor 
template<class T>
cMatrix<T>::cMatrix(unsigned _rows, unsigned _cols, const T& _initial)
    : mat(_rows,std::vector<T>(_cols,_initial))
    , rows(_rows)
    , cols(_cols)
{
}

//VirtualDestructor
template<class T>
cMatrix<T>::~cMatrix() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

`mat1` and `mat4` can be destroyed after `CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` call, move declaration of variable to own block.

```
int main() 
{
  {
    cMatrix<double> mat1(2, 3, 23.0), mat4(2, 3, 15.0);
  }
  CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten some advice giving one possible way to deal with the problem you've seen. At least IMO, there's a somewhat better way though. Instead of mixing the diagnostic code with the other code, then adding braces to introduce a scope that's irrelevant to the real code, I'd separate the leak-dumping code even more completely, by putting it into a separate class:

```
struct leak_dumper { 
    ~leak_dumper() { _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); }
} dump_leaks_at_exit;
```

This creates a global instance of the object, so you can simply add these three lines of code to the same file that contains your `main` (or `WinMain`) and it'll do the leak-dumping after `main` exits (with no other modification of your existing code).

As far as how to define a 2D matrix goes: a vector of vectors generally makes sense *only* if different rows of the matrix might contain different numbers of columns. If you want a rectangular matrix, you're generally better off with a single vector, and converting 2D coordinates to one dimension in an overloaded operator.

```
template <class T>
class matrix2D { 
     std::vector<T> data;
     int columns;
public:
     T &operator()(int x, int y) {
         return data[y * columns + x];
     }

     matrix2D(int x, int y) : data(x*y), columns(x) {}
};
```

This reduces the total memory you use and, perhaps more importantly, keeps the data contiguous instead of allocating the data for each row separately.